# Pandas merge two dataframes by time column

Tags: python, datetime, pandas, time, merge

I have been struggling to merge data frames. I need to have the rows arranged by the time, with both sets of data's columns merged into a new data frame. I'm sorry if this is clearly documented somewhere, but it has been hard for me to find an appropriate method. I tried `append` and `merge` but I am struggling to find an appropriate solution.

dataframe1:

```
     # Date Time, GMT-07:00  Crossflow (Cold) (Volts)  \
0        1           8:51:00 AM                   1.13431   
1        2           8:51:01 AM                   1.12821   
2        3           8:51:02 AM                   1.12943   
3        4           8:51:03 AM                   1.12759   
4        5           8:51:04 AM                   1.13065   
5        6           8:51:05 AM                   1.12821   
6        7           8:51:06 AM                   1.12943   
7        8           8:51:07 AM                   1.13065   
8        9           8:51:08 AM                   1.13126   
9       10           8:51:09 AM                   1.13126   
10      11           8:51:10 AM                   1.12821
```

dataframe2:

```
         # Date Time, GMT-07:00  \
0        1           9:06:39 AM   
1        2           9:06:40 AM   
2        3           9:06:41 AM   
3        4           9:06:42 AM   
4        5           9:06:43 AM   
5        6           9:06:44 AM   
6        7           9:06:45 AM   
7        8           9:06:46 AM   
8        9           9:06:47 AM   
9       10           9:06:48 AM   
10      11           9:06:49 AM   
      K-Type, °C (LGR S/N: 10118625, SEN S/N: 10118625)  
0                                                 43.96  
1                                                 47.25  
2                                                 48.90  
3                                                 50.21  
4                                                 43.63  
5                                                 43.63  
6                                                 42.97  
7                                                 42.97  
8                                                 42.30  
9                                                 41.64  
10                                                40.98
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that you want to `append` the dataframes to each other. Make sure that your date column has the *same name* in both dataframes otherwise pandas will treat them as two totally separate columns.

```
df = dataframe1.append(dataframe2, ignore_index=True)
```

Comment: Also, this blog post is a good resource for `join` and `merge` in pandas. http://www.gregreda.com/2013/10/26/working-with-pandas-dataframes/#joining